# How can I get a button to fully execute a Macro in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, button

When I execute the following macro without a button, The shapes will delete beautifully. When I execute the macro with a button, the shapes are selected, but they are not deleted. I don't understand why. Is there something wrong with the code? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub DeleteAllObjects()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Flowchart")

    ws.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Delete
 End Sub
```

Comment: I would right click your button and verify that you have it set to the correct macro. I've had massive headaches because the button is assigned to a macro that was in a different version of the same workbook ;)

Comment: This code appears to only delete the shapes if ws is active.

Comment: You could also try to optimize your code a bit more. Something like:
Worksheets("Flowchart").shapes.delete

Comment: Thank you, Blake! When a code doesn't execute like I want it, I usually assume that I made an error and recheck it. Fortunately, the button was assigned to the correct macro. Also, I used the Macro recorder to start writing the code and noticed that it specified the deletion from the "Active Sheet". So I rewrote the code, thinking that I was outsmarting the recorder. Lesson learned! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used an iterative approach because my observation was that your method did not work if the `ws` was not Active at runtime (and to [avoid the spaghetti-code of needlessly activating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)).

Your problem is because the Excel `Selection` only exists relative to the `ActiveSheet`, so when you do `Selection.Delete` you're actually deleting something on the `ActiveSheet`, which isn't the same as the `ws`!

I have tested this and it works when called from button (on another sheet) or when invoked manually from  <kbd>F5</kbd>  in the IDE.

```
 Sub DeleteAllObjects()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim s As Long

 Set ws = Worksheets(3)
 For s = ws.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    ws.Shapes(s).Delete
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: David Zemens, thank you so much! This worked perfectly!

Comment: @CPILon cheers, please consider voting up, or Accepting the answer if it solves the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers